# PDF Module in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using the pdf module version 0.9, and i have some troubles in
renderPDF.

I always get this message:

Oops: CConvertException

An unexpected error occured caused by exception CConvertException:
ERROR: An unhandled exception occured:
com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(I)[I

My method in controller is very simple:

```
public static void showTermo(Long id) {
        User user = User.findById(id);
        renderPDF(user);
    }
```

TNks

**UPDATE**

I'm testing now whitout arguments..and the exception continues.

```
public static void showTermo() {            
        renderPDF();
    }
```

In my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello
</body>
</html>
```

Tnks

Answer (score 1):

I have also received this error when an HTML Element is not closed properly. For example, inside a `<table>` element I had `</th` instead of `</th>`. In order to find the faulty line, I just deleted chunks of the view to narrow down my scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this because the `renderPDF` method needs the input to be either in the PDF or HTML template.

> The renderPDF will first look for a .pdf template. If there are none,
>   it will fall back to the .html template. You can use a media=“print” css to customize the PDF to render. The result is a PDF file. The render method uses the same template as for rendering HTML.
>
> Please refer to the samples-and-test for an example.

Since you are using a `User`, it can't map this to a PDF or HTML template from your model.

[Here](https://github.com/pepite/play--pdf/blob/master/samples-and-tests/pdf/app/controllers/Application.java)  is a link to the example `Application.java` controller provided on GitHub for examples on how to use this method properly.

Comment: Tnks for answer Dan. In example, the view generate.html is calling with arguments content, options and title. I'm trying now render a simply view, without pass User....and i got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!
In my lib folder, i have a jar iText 2.1.0 for ticket generation..... useless now =(
Do not remember him ....

Tnks

Comment: I do not quite understand the answer. What actually fixed the problem - adding or removing the iText jar?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran across the same Exception myself, and tracked it down to a problem with fontawesome. We just upgraded fontawesome to 3.2.1 and that caused the problem to start. The html file that was being rendered included the stylesheet for fontawesome:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/font-awesome.css'}">
```

As soon as I removed that link, the exception went away.

I got the idea that it was a fontawesome issue because the stack trace included an importFontFaces method.

Fortunately for me, the html file in question did not actually make use of fontawesome, so there were no side effects.